# Render dictionary in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have groupby clause built in a django view and then I intend to display the dictionary created in a template. The problem here is that the template instead of displaying values, displays the header fields repeated (screenshot attached so it makes more sense). Any assistance will be appreciated !

Here is the view

```
def did_count_region_groupby(request):
    region_carrier_groupby = DID_Definition_Model.objects.all().values('region_carrier').annotate(DID_Count=Count('region_carrier')).order_by('DID_Count')
    region_carrier_groupby_dict = {'region_carrier_groupby' : region_carrier_groupby}

    return render(request, 'MASTERHANDLER/did_count_region_groupby.html', region_carrier_groupby_dict)
```

and here is the template

```
{% for key, value in region_carrier_groupby %}
        <tr>

            <td> {{key}}</td> <td>{{value}}</td>



        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`values()` on a queryset will return a list of dictionaries. So you have to iterate over it as:

```
{% for listing region_carrier_groupby %}
    {% for key, value in listing.items %}
            <tr>

                <td> {{key}}</td> <td>{{value}}</td>



            </tr>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add `.items` `region_carrier_groupby.items`

```
{% for key, value in region_carrier_groupby.items %}
            <tr>

                <td> {{key}}</td> <td>{{value}}</td>



            </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

[Django documentation built-ins for](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for)

Comment: On using the code below the output displayed  blank page -

```
{% for key,value in region_carrier_groupby.items %}
{{ key }}: {{ value }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: what do you have in your `region_carrier_groupby ` is it a type of dict()?

Comment: check if the region_carrier_groupby is a dict instance

Comment: so I ran the following code now -

```

{% for listings in region_carrier_groupby %}
    {{listings}}
    
{% endfor %}
```

it produced the following result on webpage -

```
{'region_carrier': 'airtel - blg', 'DID_Count': 1} {'region_carrier': 'tc1 - rc1', 'DID_Count': 2}
```

Comment: yeah now i added as in your template

Comment: ooh then go {{listings.region_carrier}}  - {{listings.DID_Count}}

Comment: here is my final html template, and it works great ! Thank you @ThunderHorn.

```
 <table class="content-table">
  <thead>
   <tr>
    <th>Region Carrier DID</th>
    <th>Count</th>

           
    
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

{% for listing in region_carrier_groupby %}
 
            <tr>

                <td> {{listing.region_carrier}}</td> <td>{{listing.DID_Count}}</td>



            </tr>
   
{% endfor %}



 
  </tr>
 


 </tbody></table>

```